# Can you "buy" a feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Okay, no-one likes my [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29939/feature-request-safeoverflow). So there appears to be zero chance of it being implemented automatically. The masses hath spoken. :)

So, are there any other options aside from following the ["we don't serve *your* type"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29931/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-no-cursing-rule/29947#29947) advice? Perhaps you also have a feature that would be cool but no-one else likes.

So I ask since we're all software devs and software devs have cash..... could we pay the SO team to implement a feature? I'd like to be able to swear again and would pay for the privilege.

Comment: w​​​​h​​​a​​​​t

Comment: Happy Birthday Welbog - this is your gift...

Comment: Are you on crack? Just get Sampson to write you a Grease Monkey script that inserts profanity every few words. Or just read my profile every 10-15 minutes (like I do - it helps deal with the rampant whininess of Meta's userbase).

Comment: software devs have cash???????

Comment: If you bought some advertising space you might be able to talk the dev team into implementing a feature for you.. you'd probably still have to ask very nicely though :)

Comment: Grease Monkey + Welbog = WIN

Comment: Wait it doesn't work that way round. Inserting swears randomly is stupid. I want to use them in the first place.

Comment: Technically, you can curse all you want, it'll just get flagged.

Comment: According to the rules I will get suspended/banned. Also the original content will be modified.

Comment: God how I want those super mega downvotes right now. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/foo/29935#29935

Comment: Yea go for the mega downvotes. As far as i'm concered all three questions I have asked are consistent and fair. I could just whinge about the rule but instead I am trying to see if there is a technological solution instead.

Comment: @Quibblesome: Stop whining about downvotes. It's not like anyone whose opinion matters downvoted you...

Comment: Yea i'm whining a bit. I just find it strange that what I believe to be a number of consistent and fair questions in the spirit of the site are being downvoted into obscurity.

Comment: @Quibblesome: Downvotes mean the people do not agree with you. You're allowed to have opinions and so are they. The well-wordedness and soundness of your suggestions aren't what're in question here.

Comment: @Quibblesome: Understand that on Meta, downvoting often means you simply disagree with the proposal. I disagree with you attempting to buy a feature, I cannot describe how much I disagree with trying to implement a "Safe" mode (even Google can't get that right, and they have a veritable army of Really Smart People), and while I wish I could cuss on SO (especially right about **now**), I respect the site owner's pragmatic wishes on it and let it go. Troggy H. Welbog on a flying Pesto!

Comment: Wait, but disagreeing also takes it off the front page. Is that intentional? On SO -1 is for just wrong stuff, it's wrong it doesn't make sense, or its spam so it gets pushed off the main page. This is pushed off the main page because people don't agree with it. Is that right?

Comment: @Quibblesome: Welcome to meta.

Comment: I have to take exception to all the people downvoting this question. Just because you feel the answer to a question is a resounding no, doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: @Kevin Laity: Welcome to Meta. Downvotes already explained several times on this post alone.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure if you offered enough money, Jeff & *Co* would find the resources to implement it somewhere.  It is a business, after all.

But I suspect the price is more than you can afford, as they have to weigh not only the costs to implement and maintain the feature, but the potential change in viewership and how that might impact revenue (and they seem to believe it would cost them a measurable number of users) and also how it would impact their staffing, etc.

Comment: It's more than a box of donuts? Awwwww.

Comment: ... Do the donuts have ... *sprinkles* ... ?

Comment: Do you *want* them to have sprinkles?

Comment: You are *not* talking about sex, right? That sentence exchange sounded dirty... *shrugs*

Answer (score 4):

I've long been a supporter of the [swear jar idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/potential-stackoverflow-revenue-models/24423#24423). It gives we <strike>drunks</strike>free-spirited individuals an opportunity to speak our minds and it gives Jeff lots of money. It's win-win!

Comment: So now we just need a place to enter our CC#!

Comment: @Welbog: you'd finance SOFU for a year with your profile alone. +1

Answer (score 2):

> So there appears to be zero chance of
>   it being implemented automatically.

What what *what?!* Features never get implemented automatically, they don't exist "by default." The feature you suggested would take considerable time and effort to develop, and likely would not be implemented to the same quality standards as the rest of SO, simply because it is nigh-impossible to do correctly. (This isn't a knock on the SO team, it's a knock on the feature. If you can't do something correctly -- and that feature couldn't be done such -- then don't do it.)

While they were building that feature, a bunch of others which are being considered won't be getting built. Ones which were more popular with the community.

That, and unless you could offer enough to pay the developer(s) in question for their time adequately (I don't know what they make, but think three figures an hour for their total cost) you probably can't afford it.

I'm not even sure the question makes welb_gging sense.

Comment: Cute. I see what you did there, Jon B. :)

Comment: That's B_rthday Welb_gging sense to you, Jon.

Comment: By automatically I meant that the community loves it and upvotes it so very much that SO implements it "for free/automatically". I feel strongly about this issue, therefore I am looking to see if there are any routes to goal. If a route exists that costs money then it is still a viable route.

Comment: If the route costs money -- how much do you have to spend on this? What's it really worth, in dollars, to you? Because my off-the-cuff response on something like this is at least 40 - 80 hours, and at a cheap $100 an hour, that's a lot of beans just to be able to cuss at will. Get a blog and cuss there. Cheaper.

Comment: @Cigars: I do that too! I'm way ahead of the pack here.

Comment: @welb_g: I know. And I love the window pane-type effect on the right-hand images. Those are slick.

Comment: Original content is important to me. This is more an ethical concern, like the same way people take up teaching even though the pay is terrible. Your worst case scenario is $8000. That's roughly £5,000. Yes, I would consider that.

Comment: @Cigars: You're slick.

Comment: @Quibblesome - there are starving people in the world and you would pay $8,000 to swear on SO? Now I feel like I need to swear on SO.

Comment: That's off the cuff without seeing the code. The only person who could answer the cost question is Jeff. E-mail team@stackoverflow.com and I'm sure, were he to entertain your request, he could get you a quote.

Comment: There are starving people in the world and we're sitting here discussing this on metaoverflow when we could be helping them. Go figure.

Comment: You win the non-sequitur of the day award. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to DiBiase, **Everybody has a price**

I'm relatively certain that if you were to offer Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky $256,000,000[USD] then they would be only too happy to turn Stackoverflow over to you lock stock and barrel, nevermind implementing your 'feature'.

Given that such a price must exist, the rest is quibbling.

"Madam, we’ve already established that. Now we are haggling about the price."

Comment: I'd be sold by $256[USD]. If only because the geekiness would make me want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to swear again and would pay for the **privilege**?

Please read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29931/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-no-cursing-rule/29950#29950) on [What is the rationale behind the “no cursing” rule?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29931/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-no-cursing-rule) question:

> Jeff Atwood:
>   If you can't effectively communicate what you need to say without resorting to lowest common denominator cursing, then keep it to yourself.
>
> Translation:
>   If you are not comfortable with the [site policy], this may not be the
>   site for you.

Comment: We're missing the bit where it states the "why". The why is to bypass corporate firewalls. I therefore want to implement a solution that bypasses corporate firewalls but keeps the original content intact. ANYWAY, this is not answering the question. The question is can you buy a feature.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that you should just tell your firewall admin(s) to grow-up....  That seems a bit draconian, even for my organization.

Comment: @squillman: Exactly. The no-swearing policy on SO is a wrong to fix a wrong. Two wrongs don't make a right. We should take the high road and allow everyone to swear all they shogging want.

Comment: Welbog, we can't do that cause people like Adam Davies are behind corporate firewalls. They wouldn't be able to read the site. It would be AS wrong of us to deny them access as it is to prevent people from swearing. We just need to work around the firewall. We can do it!

Comment: I'm prepared to lose Adam Davies.

Comment: Yes but you're mean. :P. I like Adam, some of his posts are very good.

Comment: @Quibblesome: we can't do that cause people like Adam Davies implement or deploy stupid corporate firewalls. FTFY